# Jquery Index() returns -1

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, indexing

I have this below function where html is getting created in Javascript. In `test(test1)` i am checking test1.Test__c null or not and changing the color.
`.table-striped > tbody > tr.testcss`" --> is changing the row color.

But i am getting

```
var id=$( ".table-striped > tbody > tr.testcss" ).index() --> -1.
```

What i am getting is in my condition, by that time row is not built for that reason index is returning -1.

Can anyone tell how to resolve this.

```
function ttttttt(test1) {
    var styleClass = "testcss";

    var html = '<tr class="' + styleClass + '" id="' + test1.Id +'">';
    return html + test(test1);
}


function test(test1) {
    var html = '<td class="cell col-md-2">' +'</td>';

    var opt = test.Test__c;
    if(oppchek === undefined){
        var id=$( ".table-striped > tbody > tr.testcss" ).index();
       );
        ++id;
    } else {
    }
    return html;
}
```

Comment: Share any working example which best explain

Comment: Please click the `<>` snippet editor and create a [mcve]

Comment: can you please share you code at jsfiddle ...

Comment: please find working at jsfiddle , linke provided in my answer ..please do accept upvote if works you

Comment: Are you trying to make changes with jquery to some html before the html has been added to the DOM?  You can do that with this type of code:  `var html = '<td...'; $("<div>").html(html); $(div).find(".testcss") ...` ? but that makes no sense with the snippet you've provided (not enough html in the html variable).

Answer (score 0):

Working at jsFiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/pranayamr/rkcxqyw9/3/

```
alert($('table > tbody > tr.testcss').index());
```

---

```
//if you want to work on all tr having `testcss` than do like this 
$('table > tbody > tr.testcss').each(function(){
       alert($(this).index());
})
```

Comment: @freedomn-m - yes agree experimenting things ...updated now

Comment: hi all.. I got what the issue was.. The issue was in the place where i was writing the code at that the table was not built..